# json_encode works for integers not for strings

Tags: javascript, php, json, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to pass arrays from php to js and the json_encode function works on $MID (integer array) but fails to do anything on $name (array of strings).

Can anybody help me understand why it won't work?

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [materialID],[name],[categoryName],[materialResponsePerson] 
        FROM [SAP_Replication].[dbo].[IntranetProductResponsePerson]";

$params = array();
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$MID = array();
$name = array();
$cName = array();
$resPerson = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     array_push($MID,$row["materialID"]);
     array_push($name,$row["name"]);
     array_push($cName,$row["categoryName"]);
     array_push($resPerson,$row["materialResponsePerson"]);
}

echo json_encode($MID); //works and returns values
echo json_encode($name); //returns bool(false)

sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: Can you show us a `var_dump($name)` please

Comment: What does `json_last_error` return? What are the data type and collation of the `name` column?

Comment: It clearly works with strings in general - it would be pretty ridiculous if it didn't, don't you think? Therefore we can be pretty certain that if there's an issue, it's going to be an issue with the specific string you're using. Therefore you need to show us a string (or strings) which is causing the problem.

Comment: When you say "returns null", do you mean that "null" is what ends up in the response body? Like, the string "null"? Is it bracketed, like `["null"]`? From what you posted, that variable `$name` should be an array, and even an empty array would end up as `[ ]` in the JSON response text.

Answer (score 3):

Only echo one thing back to the Javascript! It is expecting to get one reply from your PHP code and not 4.

so I would do

```
echo json_encode([  'MID'       => $MID, 
                    'name'      => $name, 
                    'cName'     => $cName,
                    'resPerson' => $resPerson
                ]);
```

Then change your js code to read data from the right object

Answer (score 0):

I have made a mistake when commenting the code. When I var_dump the $name variable it returns bool(false). Later I found out that meant that json_encode doesn't support string which have 'đ','ž','...' in them so I need to convert the array to utf-8.
Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: As an option you may try to change the `CharacterSet` connection [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?view=sql-server-ver15) in the `sqlsrv_connect()` call to `UTF-8` (by default it's `SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR`).